# Tweepy, how to correctly format output to csv file?

Tags: python, csv, tweepy

I'm attempting to search twitter using some keywords to find tweets with the keywords on a particular day and write the tweets to a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import tweepy as tw
import datetime

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)


search_words = ["chelsea","liverpool"]
date_since = "2020-07-19"

startDate = datetime.datetime(2020,7,22,0,0,0)
endDate = datetime.datetime(2020,7,23,0,0,0)

# Collect tweets
for i in search_words:
    new_search = i + " -filter:retweets"
    tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                  q=new_search, 
                  lang="en",
                  since=date_since,tweet_mode="extended").items(1000)


    # Iterate and print tweets
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.created_at < endDate and tweet.created_at > startDate:  
            dfObj = dfObj.append({"Tweets": tweet.full_text},ignore_index=True)

dfObj.to_csv(r'tweet.csv',header=True)
```

The csv file has characters like:

```
 ðŸ¥´ðŸ¥´ â€
```

How do I get rid of these characters or enter them in the csv correctly?

Also is there any way to search for multiple keywords without looping through a list? For example searching for any tweet containing the phrases 'chelsea' or 'liverpool'?

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing last block of code with this:

```py
with open("tweets.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.created_at < endDate and tweet.created_at > startDate:
            f.write("%s\n"% (tweet.full_text.encode("utf-8")))
```